# Does PHP ignore comment characters?

Tags: php, comments

This is a case where a script worked last week, but not now. I can only think that a new(er) version of PHP was installed at the web host and that version has a bug. If it's my fault, I can't see how. So, is this a PHP bug, a [GoDaddy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoDaddy) problem, or what?

Below is only a piece of the entire script, but I have reduced it down to this small failing fragment named 'a.php'. For the ones that fail, Internet Explorer says 'This page can’t be displayed' after the submit button is clicked; other browsers also show failure.

No errors appear in the PHP error log file. It appears that the comment characters are being ignored. 'allow_url_fopen' is true, but the statement shouldn't be part of the running script anyway.

This is using PHP v5.3.24 and v5.4.19 on multiple shared Linux hostings on GoDaddy. I tried these examples on a local [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)#Variants) installation (with PHP v5.6.0 or v5.4.23) and they all work.

Note that I had to turn "http" into "httpX" in the below examples to get this posted.

In the full script, I used the last method to get it working again, i.e. move the URL string into a variable and use that variable as the function's argument.

These three fail:

```
// Commented line at the end
print "<form action=\"a.php\" method=\"POST\">";
print "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" /></p>";
print "</form>";
//file_get_contents('httpX://abc.com');

// Commented line at the beginning
//file_get_contents('httpX://abc.com');
print "<form action=\"a.php\" method=\"POST\">";
print "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" /></p>";
print "</form>";

// Use other commenting characters
print "<form action=\"a.php\" method=\"POST\">";
print "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" /></p>";
print "</form>";
/*file_get_contents('httpX://abc.com');*/
```

These four work as expected:

```
// Remove offending line
print "<form action=\"a.php\" method=\"POST\">";
print "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" /></p>";
print "</form>";

// Change function name
print "<form action=\"a.php\" method=\"POST\">";
print "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" /></p>";
print "</form>";
//zile_get_contents('httpX://abc.com');

// Change from URL to file
print "<form action=\"a.php\" method=\"POST\">";
print "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" /></p>";
print "</form>";
//file_get_contents(b.txt);

// Set var to URL and use var as argument
print "<form action=\"a.php\" method=\"POST\">";
print "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" /></p>";
print "</form>";
//$u = 'httpX://abc.com';
//file_get_contents($u);
```

Comment: @ElefantPhace He has a script that was working last week, and stopped working now, he's asking if there is something bad in the script that he doesn't see, he's assuming that the comment characters `//` are being ignored by php

Comment: They are ignored, they're comments. All he has is three identical empty forms. What is your expected output?

Comment: What text editor are you using, and have you looked at your encoding character set?  Also have you displayed all characters in the script, not just the normal visible ones?  And how are the error defaults set up from ini files or wherever?  (BTW, your html is not well formed, but you prob. already know that, e.g. you can't put input directly inside form, but need to have form, div, input.)  And what' with all of the slashes?  Just use a single quote inside the double quotes.

Comment: What errors are you getting when the script runs?  What out put is being printed, if any?

Comment: Along with the exact errors you are experiencing, can you post all of the code?

Comment: @Eliptical ... Yes you can put inputs directly into forms. There is no need to add a div or anything else...

Comment: @el', won't validate in xhtml, and the only reason it is ok otherwise is because browsers allow for it in more loose html.  But it's not standardized other than that.  Forgive me if I write only in xhtml these days, but having tried different ways over the years, I came to like the strict rules and validation.  With them I find I can more often count on browsers to interpret my html accurately all of the time.

Comment: @ElefantPhace The actual question is: How can characters inside a comment affect the running of a script? The complete code is shown except for the "< ? php" which I can't include. Each of those blocks is the entire script - see the comments in the first lines.

Comment: @Eliptical-view No errors are reported; as I said IE shows 'This page can’t be displayed'; FF shows 'The connection was reset - The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.'; Chrome shows 'No data received'; Safari shows an empty screen. I've looked at the file with WinHex and there are no unicode or other strange extras. Removing an extraneous closing p tag and moving to single quotes doesn't change the behavior. I'll post a cleaned up, W3C validated file that displays the behavior. The original post shows what did and didn't let the script work.

Comment: <?php // commented line at end
    echo '<!DOCTYPE html>';
    echo '<head>';
    echo '<meta charset="UTF-8">';
    echo '<title>title</title>';
    echo '</head>';
    echo '<body>';
    echo '<form action="a.php" method="post">';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" />';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</body>';
    echo '</html>';
    //file_get_contents('httpX://abc.com');
    ?>

Comment: @arrowd, they can't. They are comments. They aren't parsed. Add your comment to your question...

Comment: @ElefantPhace If you read my original post, you'll see that in this very specific case, those characters are not being treated as comments even though they're in a comment area. For some reason, the system is interpreting them somehow and causing the script to fail.

Comment: I seriously doubt that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **major problem with GoDaddy hosting**. Recently, some of my PHP scripts generated this ill server response.

I issued a ticket, and of course a response is being delayed (not just by the server). Their usual holdback is anticipated as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "holdback"? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your update was useful:

> as I said IE shows 'This page can’t be displayed';

> FF shows 'The connection was reset - The connection to the server was reset while
> the page was loading.';

> Chrome shows 'No data received';

> Safari shows an empty screen.

Your web server isn't configured or working properly.

First, create a simple html page with no php, and try to see if you can view that.  If not look at any .htaccess file you have, and possibly just remove it temporarily.  Or get GoDaddy to help you.

Here's an example page.  Call it test.htm and put it in your server root:

```
Hello world.
```

If you can view a simple html page, then it's a php problem.  Try a really simple php page.  Call it test.php and make it this:

```
<?php echo "Hi from php";?>
```

!!! MAKE SURE YOU'RE EDITOR ENCODING IS NOT SET TO USE 'BOM'.  Set it for simple ANSI/ASCII for now.

I know it can be frustrating, but you will get this fixed, and then whack yourself upside the head at how simple it was.

Comment: This is a fairly large site with lots of pages, lots of MySQL interplay, lots of JS, etc. and everything works fine except this one script that only started barfing last week. As I said, I do have it working now by moving the URL arg from a string in the func call into a variable and using that variable as the arg for file_get_contents call. I really was expecting to see that other GoDaddy users had either noticed this or were able to duplicate it. This is the weirdest thing I've ever seen. I agree with you that there is a web server problem but it seems to be with the PHP interpreter. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check for BOM on that page?  I mean if it's just one page, then that points very much to that one page, and actually not to GoDaddy.  my 2c.